# Can't get prepared statements in PHP to work with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

In the `mysql` console I have this

```sql
mysql> SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `tblStudents` WHERE `idStudent`='2';
+--------------+-----------------+
|     name     |    lastname     |
+--------------+-----------------+
|     Lucio    |    Martínez     |
+--------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I want to get the name and last name of this student using prepared statements in PHP.

This is the code:

```php
$mysqli = $this->ConnectLowPrivileges();
echo 'Connected<br>';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `tblStudents` WHERE `idStudent`=?");
if (false==$stmt){
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
$id = 2;
if ($rc = $stmt->execute(array($id))){
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "Name: {$row[0]}.<br>Last name: {$row[1]}.<br>";
        echo 'Another way:'.print_r($row);
    }
}
if (false==$rc){
    die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
echo 'done';
mysqli_close($mysqli);
return true;
```

The second conditional gives false and the output that I get is this:

```
Connected
execute() failed:
```

PHP is make the connection with the database without problems.

I can't know the exact error because `$stmt->error` returns nothing.

Comment: You need to get yourself some tutorial first. Using just random operators off your head will do no good. A simple Google search for "mysqli tutorial" should be enough for starter. Once you get to such a tutorial, try to run the very examples they offer. Once make yourself familiar with them, you may start adopting these example codes for your needs.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've been searching since a week, reading posts, articles, tried several codes. But I can't get it work.

Comment: You need to [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) using the MySQLi class., `execute` doesn't allow the binding of parameters (Unless you use PDO).  So, bind the parameter `$id` and your query should run.

Comment: @Jon So after use `bind_param()` I need to run `execute()` or not?

Comment: Yes, the query isn't ran until you execute it, binding a parameter just puts it in place so you can run it.

Comment: @Jon If I try to [add that sentence](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5668581/) it enter in the line 8 but it show `Name: .Lastname: .`.

Comment: Okay, you were reading articles. Which code from which article did you particularly try?

Comment: @Lucio nevermind. I was wrong.

Comment: @Jon If I do so, that conditional is not entered.

Comment: Yes, I did. But still I get no luck. You can know that I'm trying it looking [the code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5668623/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid further comments, read all the comments and links I posted on the question to understand, and change code to:

```
$mysqli = $this->ConnectLowPrivileges();
echo 'Connected<br>';
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT `name`, `lastname` FROM `tblStudents` WHERE `idStudent`=?");

$id = 2;
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $lastname);
    if ($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "Name: {$name}<br>Last name: {$lastname}<br>";
        //echo 'Another way:'.print_r($row, true); //won't work with bind_result
    } else {
        echo "No results";
    }
} else {
    die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
echo 'done';
stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: I just tryied your code and it prints "Connected", it doesn't show even "done".

Comment: Try it again, forgot to add `stmt_init()` the first time I posted the answer.

Comment: I added it and I get exactly the same results.

Comment: Added an `else` statement in there.  If 'done' isn't being `echo`'d, then there is something else wrong.

Comment: Now I know that, after the `$rc = $stmt->get_result();` line it stop. I've added an `echo` after it and it is not printing.

Comment: Ok, seems your compiled version doesn't support that command - try the updated code now, binding the results.